# Splitting a ruby file at a pattern?

Tags: ruby, regex, file, split, partitioning

I have a large ruby file that contains product data. I'm trying to split the file into sections based on a regular expression. I have product headers denoted by the word `Product` followed by a space and then a number. After that, I have a bunch of lines containing product information.

The format looks like this.

> Product 1:
>
> ```
> ...data
> ```
>
> Product 2:
>
> ...data
>
> ...
>
> Product N:
>
> ...data

When reading from the file, I would like to ignore the Product Headers and instead only show the product data. For that, I'm trying to split the file based on a regular expression.

```
file = File.read('products.txt')
products = file.split(/\Aproduct \d+:\z/i)
```

This regex works and finds all product headers. The problem is, the file isn't being split into the appropriate sections.

When I run `puts products[0],` the entire file gets printed out to the console.

Comment: You may want to experiment with `Enumerable#slice_before`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\A` and `\z` match the beginning and end of a string, respectively. While what you want is to match the beginning and end of a line. Instead, you should use `^` and `$`anchors:

```
/^product \d+:$/i
```

Answer (score 1):

The file will be readed complete, there's no way to avoid it. But you can iterate over each line and ignore the one that matches the expresion:

```
File.open("file.txt", "r") do |file|
  file.each_line do |line|
    if # condition
    #fancy stuff
    else
    # not that fancy
  end
end
```

Comment: How are you going to skip a line baseD on the content without reading it?

Comment: Never mind, I thought you were saying you had to slurp the entire file at once.